# laravel run script through command line not accessible through browser

Tags: laravel, scripting

I would like to write an application using Laravel framework which imports CSV in the database but it will be runnable from command line ONLY and will not be accessible through browser. Any ideas how can I run it only through command line and not by using routes/browser?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/artisan

Comment: @user3158900 thank you very much.